# Promise returned as undefined

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to return a promise but getting undefined.Please find below the code

```
fnCompare: function ( paramA, paramB){

    var compObj = new CompFn({
       //Initiate some Values here
    });


    return compObj.doCheck().then(function(data){       
        return data;

    });     
}
```

Calling Function -

```
asyncFunc.fnCompare(paramOne,paramTwo).then( function(data){

    console.log("Found differences: " + data.desc);
    assert.equal(data.code,expectedValue);

}, function(err) {
      throw err;
});
```

Getting the error - Cannot call then of undefined. Any help would be useful. I tried to implement this using a solution provided here, but perhaps doing something wrong.

Comment: It sounds like `doCheck()` isn't returning anything (making it's result `undefined`). Do you have the code for `CompFn` and specifically `doCheck`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad, got the problem. The doCheck() function was expecting a callback and my function was designed to accept a promise from doCheck(). Promise.denodify(this.doCheck) solved the issue.